# repace n occurrences of a character in a string from the end

Tags: regex, sed

I am struggling to come up with a solution to replace n occurrences of a character with another character in a string starting from the end of the string. For example, if I want to replace last 5 occurrences of "," with "|" in a string like

```
abc, def,,{"data":{"xyz":null,"uan":"5643df"},{"path":"/abc/def/xyz"}},546,453,,,
```

to get a result like

```
abc, def,,{"data":{"xyz":null,"uan":"5643df"},{"path":"/abc/def/xyz"}}|546|453|||
```

I have looked at multiple solution which helps you find the last occurrence or all occurrences or 5 occurrences from the beginning but nothing which helps me do it from the end of the string. Reversing the string and doing it from the beginning and then reversing the string again is not an option because of the sheer size of the file.

Comment: Welcome to SO, have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: yes i did try to play with various sed commands and also looked around for what is available on the net.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18303/sed-delete-all-occurrences-of-a-string-except-the-first-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed. Replace five times last comma and rest of row with pipe and rest of row (`s/,([^,]*)$/|\1/`):

```
echo 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h' | sed -r 's/,([^,]*)$/|\1/; s/,([^,]*)$/|\1/; s/,([^,]*)$/|\1/; s/,([^,]*)$/|\1/; s/,([^,]*)$/|\1/;'
```

Output:

```
a,b,c|d|e|f|g|h
```

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version:

```
echo 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h' | awk -F, '{printf "%s",$1;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf (NF-5<i?"|%s":",%s"),$i;print ""}'
a,b,c|d|e|f|g|h
```

It uses a loop to print each field.  Count up and find when to use `,` or `|`.  Number can be changed to get other result.

Example last to field:

```
echo 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h' | awk -F, '{printf "%s",$1;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf (NF-2<i?"|%s":",%s"),$i;print ""}'
a,b,c,d,e,f|g|h
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed  -E '/(,[^,]*){5}$/{s//\n&/;h;y/,/|/;H;g;s/\n.*\n//}' file
```

Insert a newline just before the fifth comma from the end of a line, make a copy, replace all `,`'s by `|`'s, append the current line to the copy and remove everything between the first and last newlines.

An alternative using GNU parallel and sed:

```
parallel -n0 -q echo 's/\(.*\),/\1|/' ::: {1..5} | sed -f - file
```

N.B. The first solution only amends the a line if there are at least 5 commas whereas the second solution amends a line regardless of how many commas there are.